# Wobble effects not working in Compiz

Tags: compiz, graphics

Just couple of days before installed Ubuntu 12.04 with all the necessary upgradations. Also installed Compiz Settings Manager & loved the animations & wobble effects of windows. But after restarting windows today, started receiving error messages & Wobble effects are disappeared.

Also, other settings created by me in my last login, like small sidebar icons, too disappeared & unable to find even option in "All Settings >> Appearance" to resize the icons.

Loved Ubuntu 12.04, specially Animation & Wobble effects but unhappy with these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. What happened was that my recent updates also gave me a new kernel and that bugged out with my graphics driver. I know it's my graphics driver because moving windows was so slow and blocky. I just used a previous kernel version when booting up and everything was fine.

Another possible solution is that you can purge your graphics driver and try to reinstall it while you're on the bugging kernel version. I have no idea if this will work because I'm just partly a beginner myself.

Comment: Try Preproposed Compiz

Comment: I just did a re-install instead, not just because of that issue, it's also because I was having problems with the 64 bit OS so I have to install the 32 bit version. I don't know about if I don't know whether that would fix my past issue because my display settings were bugging out as well, and I was thinking that it caused my compiz to crash.

Answer (score 0):

## Try Preproposed Compiz

It's a bug fixed version of Compiz, works well for most.

Run the **3 commands** below in Terminal and restart your Ubuntu

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:vanvugt/compiz-preproposed.
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install compiz=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 compiz-core=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 compiz-gnome=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 compiz-plugins=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 compiz-plugins=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 compiz-plugins-default=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 libdecoration0=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2